# Transfer ownership of Oyster card

Tags: oyster-card

I own an Oyster card and it is associated with my Oyster online account only in order to check my travel history. I also manage contactless cards on my existing Oyster account. There is currently an outstanding balance but no auto topup.

I want to give this physical card, with its balance, to a friend. I want my friend to be able to register the card on the new account to access the travel history in the future and/or apply for partial journeys etc. Personally, I don't even care about making him available **my own travel history** for that Oyster card.

How can he/she transfer ownership of the card to his/her own new account?

Comment: I expect you'll have to talk to TFL: either [call them](https://tfl.gov.uk/help-and-contact/) or [use their contact form](https://tfl.gov.uk/help-and-contact/contact-us-about-oyster).

Comment: Do you have auto top-up set up on the card?

Comment: Can you update the details of your existing account with your friend’s name etc and then set up a new account in your own name?

Comment: @Traveller it works as soon as I delete my existing contactless cards and transfer them to the new account in my name

Comment: Why not give your login and password to your friend?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I succeeded in having the card refunded, thus I don't need any more to transfer the card

Comment: Your question can be useful for other people who may have a similar problem in the future, even if your own problem has been resolved — *especially* if resolved. That's how the Stack Exchange works. Don't close your own question because of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's not possible.** This is a process that's not officially supported as there's no need for it. If you speak to staff in person or on the phone that is what I have been told in the past.

In practical terms, you have two options.

1) Give the other person your card. Done.

2) This is what will be suggested if you you ask them to transfer the account. They will just refund the card and balance and use this to allow your friend to get their own one. The input and output are identical to transferring ownership. It's just the only way to do it and also the easiest.